# How to get control parent DataContext for element to element databinding?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Suppose I have a user control which datacontext is bound to a VM. This VM has a property for a list MyList.

Inside this user control I have a ComboBox, I want to set following kind of xaml

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}"  IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>                      
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name"   Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <!-- ...... -->
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="User" >
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding UserID}" ></ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

but it is not working.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to do Element to Element binding here? Aren't you just trying to bind the source of this ComboBox to the MyList on your ViewModel? If so, you should be able to just do this: ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"   Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by the 'parent,' could you show more code?

Answer (score 1):

This worked form me. This was the ItemSource for a ComboBox that was within a DataGrid:

```
      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}, 
Path=DataContext.Teams}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get to the main VM from within the UserControl? take a look at this solution. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx